# Delaying a function for transition duration

Tags: jquery, animation, css, delay

How can I make this script delay for 350 miliseconds while waiting for the css3 transition to end?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var last = "";
            $("#thumbs a").click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                var graphic = $(this).attr("href");
                if(last != graphic) {
                    $("#placeholder").before( "<img src=\"" + graphic + "\" />" );
                    $("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");
                    last = graphic;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Basically, when you click, it should check to see if its been clicked within the last 350 miliseconds, and if it has, do nothing.

I've heard of the `transitionend` function, but I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: I don't see any animation, do you mean the "$("#mask").css("marginTop","-=450px");'

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's CSS3 that does the animation, which causes problems if you click to quickly. (the transtion doesn't complete, so the margin is something like -350 and 450 gets subtracted from that, and so on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After document.ready, enclose your code in a function. Perhaps "function wait(){...code here...} then use a settimeout, such as var t = setTimeout(wait,350);

Hope this helps. If not, try adding a load handler to your CSS transitioning object, then putting a setTimeout function in the load callback function. It should wait for the object to load, and set a timer to start your function 350 milliseconds after the object is loaded.

Comment: I don't think the code you provided works as intended; from the looks of it, it just calls `wait()` and then assigns the value `350` to `window.setTimeout` and the local variable `t`.

Comment: Still needs work. Don't you mean `var t = setTimeout(wait, 350);`? You don't want to call the function immediately: `wait()`, you want to pass it as a reference: `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var clickable = true;
var timer;
$('#thumbs a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(clickable){
      do stuff!
    }else{
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    clickable = false;        
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        clickable = true;
    }, 350);

});
```

Comment: I don't think this code would work. It just makes clickable false for 350 milliseconds. I don't think the if(clickable) code would run because JavaScript is asynchronous: it wouldn't wait for the settimeout before running. Clickable will be false throughout the function. Good idea though. Just needs to be moved around a bit I think.

Comment: While I would normally agree. The .click jquery function reruns every single time a user clicks. So should it get set to true it should work. I updated the code alittle too.